# Recruiter sent me a job description, I figured out who the company was

Tags: recruitment, contracts

A recruiter somehow contacted me regarding a programming contract role, and I don't recall posting my resume to them but anyhow, I told them I wasn't interested and they emailed me the job description in hopes that I may forward it to someone I know.

I googled and it seems like I was able to find a job posting by the company itself (job description looks very similar).

Are there any concerns I shoudl be aware of should I try to contact that company directly?

Comment: "I'm looking for a legal answer..." off topic, we can't help you.

Comment: The company may see it in the wrong way. The following link may offer some some help. http://www.askamanager.org/2012/09/rejected-because-i-reached-out-directly-to-the-hiring-manager.html

Comment: If you don't have a contract signed with anyone (not the recruiter and not the original employer), I don't think there's any legal problems here, so you should probably remove that from you question or risk getting this closed as off-topic.

Comment: The Moral and legal aspects are both off topic.  But you can ask about potential concerns you should have in general and that is how I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

No, go wild. Contact the company. There isn't a legal issue, because there aren't any laws anywhere about contacting a company directly for a job.

That is, in fact, *why* the recruiter won't give you the company name. Once you go through the recruiter and he *solicits* you to the company - which, incidentally, in many countries he cannot do without your express written permission - it is the *company* that is bound to only go through said recruiter.

But if he doesn't solicit you to the company, then you can go and contact the company directly. If you can do this, i would heartily advice you to, life is always easier without a middleman.

Also, ask for more money than the recruiter gave for the contract. Not too much more though - maybe only 50%. If you don't know what he was quoting, create a fair price based on market conditions, and add 50% to *that*.

Comment: 50% is pretty high, I would have think it to be more like 20-30%.

Comment: I think you need a source for " life is always easier without a middleman." I find consulting firms often provide great resources.  Further it is cheaper to hire a consultant than to hire an employee.  You are not likely to make more as an employee than as a consultant.

Comment: @user1361315 typically recruiters take at least one third of the total wage... which equates to a 50% increase from your quoted rate.

Comment: @chad i need a source for "life is always easier without a middleman"??? i think you need to look up the definition of middleman. I've never ever had a consulting firm provide a useful resource... what resources do yours provide?

Comment: @Bharal - if what you are saying is true then it should not be difficult to prove that it is "ALWAYS" easier with out the middleman.A broad and generic but definitive statement like that needs to be backed up. That is the rules of the site.

Answer (score 2):

If the company did not bother to rewrite the job description then that is the cost of doing business poorly.

- If you have previously worked with this recruiter then you might want to check your non compete.  It could be in force depending on the terms you agreed to.
- If there is no prior relationship with the company then you have no obligation to that company.
- If the ad you found is not the same then it is possible that this is not the same job.  I would proceed assuming that there is no conflict.  Retain the documents you have so that you can show how you found the position independently and did not know the positions were the same.
- Sometimes hiring managers have contacts with recruitment companies.  If you have ever worked with that firm and it shows up on your resume, then the hiring manager may look to them for a reference.  If the recruiting firm indicates that they brought that position to your attention and you cut them out, the company may decide to pass on you to avoid the potential conflict.